# What's the symbolic meaning of stones in the Tenach?

Tags: commentaries

Whether it are stones being erected, building blocks for the Temple, stones being used for the breastshield, the stones that became one etc. Stones seem to represent lots of meanings. So what exactly do they represent, what is the symbolic meaning of a stone in Tenach.

Comment: You seem to be making a big assumption. Maybe stones are just so prevalent in Tanakh, because before the age of synthetic materials, they, along with wood, and some more expensive metals, would have been very common and ubiquitous.

Comment: If the question is whether or not they have significance, you can edit that into the question to clarify. If you read that they have a particular significance, consider editing that into the question as well. In general this helps people answer the question, especially if you specify where you saw it.

Comment: Following up on what @mevaqesh said I think there's plenty of significance in specific instances of stone - substitute for the iron which represents murder, represents Klal Yisrael all trying to climb under Yaakov's head, etc. - but I don't think there's one significance for all mentions of stone. Not posting this as an answer until the OP clarifies his question a bit as per mevaqesh's suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps it would be appropriate to quote the Talmud which discusses the different euphemisms for Hashem and the Yetzer Harah - The words tzur, even, and sela - synonyms for stone, all appear and have different connotations.